# css styling checkbox look like safari in all browsers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, css

I have asp.net mvc project
and many checkboxes
client has given me psd in which chech boxes are white and black
i think black are checked
there is no check tick on any
simple is that i want to remove tip and color checked checkboxes colored black with white border.

```
<input name="24" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="24" type="hidden" value="false" />
<label for="Industry__Manufacturing__and_Technology">Industry</label>
<br />
<input name="25" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="25" type="hidden" value="false" />
<label for="Intelligence">Intelligence</label>                        
<br />
...........
```

i have like above autogenerated html.

Comment: used to this http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_custom-forms/

Comment: Photoshop, its a psd file, which is a photoshop file. Most likely you can turn of the blacktick in a layer specified by the client in photoshop. There is no code involved in that. Its a graphical design thing. You have to save it in Photoshop after your done into a png file in order to have them linked in your CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible to do using the native controls. Form elements are styled more by the OS than the browser. You'll need to use some kind of replacement technique, something like [Uniform](http://uniformjs.com/) (if you're using jQuery) will work